# How to take Teradata Database Build?

Tags: database-schema, teradata, database-backups

I'm working in Teradata Database Express 14.0

Now, I want to take a particular database build(backup all objects like tables, sp, views, udf, indexes, triggers, etc).

I tried this way, but i'm getting error:

```
TDExpress14.10.03_Sles11:~ # bteq
Enter your logon or BTEQ command:
.logon localhost/xyz
Password:xxx

BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:

ARCHIVE DATA TABLES (xyz)ALL,
RELEASE LOCK,
FILEDEF=(tddumps,/var/tddumps/dump.%UEN%.out);
```

> ERROR:

```
ARCHIVE DATA TABLES(MENTISAGENT)ALL,
         $
*** Failure 3706 Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of
the request and the word 'ARCHIVE'.
            Statement# 2, Info =10
*** Total elapsed time was 1 second.
```

*Can, anyone kindly help me to figure it out this error, and guide me how to take Teradata database backup?*

Answer (score 1):

Based on your script you try to use `ARCHIVE` syntax within `bteq`, but to backup a database you must use [Teradata's backup utility](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_15_10/Database_Administration_Tools/B035_2412_035K/2412title.html), `ARCMAIN`

Comment: should I supposed to logon in DBC user to take a build?

Comment: @VivekHarry: Your logon user must have `DUMP` rights on the object you're going to backup

Comment: I have give the rights to xyz db from DBC user :GRANT DUMP ON "DBC" TO "xyz" WITH GRANT OPTION;
And again running the same command, but still I'm getting the same error

Comment: @VivekHarry: `FILEDEF` is a runtime parameter, so it's not part of the `ARCHIVE`: http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_15_10/Database_Administration_Tools/B035_2412_035K/2412Ch04.18.058.html

Comment: Thanks you very much for responding my question very immediately. And I got the answer finally.

Answer (score 0):

1) Access Privileges: 
    GRANT DUMP ON "DBC" TO "xyz" WITH GRANT OPTION (may be optional)

2) Follow this command in the Environment(Linux):

```
TDExpress14.10.03_Sles11:~ # pwd
/root
TDExpress14.10.03_Sles11:~ # cd Documents/
TDExpress14.10.03_Sles11:~/Documents #  
    **TDExpress14.10.03_Sles11:~/Documents #   arcmain**
    04/28/2016 03:39:55   Copyright 1989-2013, TeradataCorporation.
    04/28/2016 03:39:55   All Rights Reserved.
    04/28/2016 03:39:55
    04/28/2016 03:39:55     ***   ****    ****
    04/28/2016 03:39:55    *   *  *   *  *        PROGRAM: ARCMAIN
    04/28/2016 03:39:55    *****  ****   *        RELEASE: 14.10.00.05
    04/28/2016 03:39:55    *   *  *  *   *        BUILD:120212eLX (Aug  5 2014)
    04/28/2016 03:39:55    *   *  *   *   ****
    04/28/2016 03:39:55
    04/28/2016 03:39:55  RESTARTLOG = ARCLOG160428_033954565_7353.rlg
    04/28/2016 03:39:55
    04/28/2016 03:39:55  PARAMETERS IN USE:
    04/28/2016 03:39:55
    04/28/2016 03:39:55
    04/28/2016 03:39:55
    04/28/2016 03:39:55  CHARACTER SET IN USE: ASCII                                                                                                                        
    **.logon localhost/xyz,xxx;**
    04/28/2016 03:40:25  .LOGON LOCALHOST/xyz,;
    04/28/2016 03:40:25  LOGGED ON 2 SESSIONS
    04/28/2016 03:40:25
    04/28/2016 03:40:25  DBS LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE Standard
    04/28/2016 03:40:25  DBS RELEASE 14.10.03.02
    04/28/2016 03:40:25  DBS VERSION 14.10.03.02
    04/28/2016 03:40:25
    04/28/2016 03:40:25  STATEMENT COMPLETED
    04/28/2016 03:40:25
    **archive data tables(xyz)all,release lock,file=test;**
    04/28/2016 03:42:37  archive data tables(xyz),release lock,file=test;
    04/28/2016 03:42:37
    04/28/2016 03:42:37  ARC HAS REQUESTED 4 SESSIONS, TASM HAS GRANTED IT 4 SESSIONS
    04/28/2016 03:42:37
    04/28/2016 03:42:37  UTILITY EVENT NUMBER  - 45
    04/28/2016 03:42:38  LOGGED ON    4 SESSIONS
    04/28/2016 03:42:38
    04/28/2016 03:42:38  ARCHIVING DATABASE "xyz"
    04/28/2016 03:42:40  FUNCTION "XYZZ" - 686 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:40  FUNCTION "ZZ" - 694 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:40  TABLE "ZZ1" - 608 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:40  TABLE "SB" - 478 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:40  FUNCTION "DBMSSBR_RANDOM_STRING" - 694 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:40  TABLE "SGR" -   5,280,782 BYTES, 220,000 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:40  TABLE "emp4" -  33,666 BYTES, 1,000 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  TABLE "SBRSB" - 530 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  PROCEDURE "TSHSRHTR" -  21,766 BYTES, 1 ROWS
                         ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  TABLE "HRHHW" - 864 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  TABLE "RJSRERJ" - 520 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  TABLE "SJR6J" - 732 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  TABLE "SJJR" -   1,056 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  TABLE "SHTHH" -   1,122 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  TABLE "ATDHDHDT" - 622 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  TABLE "HTAHR" - 528 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  TABLE "AHTHARHR" - 530 BYTES, 0 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  PROCEDURE "AHTAH" -  12,563 BYTES, 1 ROWS ARCHIVED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  "xyz" - LOCK RELEASED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  DUMP COMPLETED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41  STATEMENT COMPLETED
    04/28/2016 03:42:41
    **ARCMAIN TERMINATED WITH SEVERITY 0**
    04/28/2016 03:43:04  ARCMAIN TERMINATED WITH SEVERITY 0
    04/28/2016 03:43:04  *** Failure ARC0202:TERMINATED was not expected.
    04/28/2016 03:43:09  LOGGED OFF   6 SESSIONS
    04/28/2016 03:43:09  ARCMAIN TERMINATED WITH SEVERITY 12
```

3) After this, go to the /root/Documents/ folder, you can able to see the file called TEXT.

4) Backup completed.

For Reference:[Teradata Database Backup](http://datawarehouse.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/teradata-l/tara-backups-from-a-command-line-3928771)